# Nested AMPScript always going to the default content!

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

My nested AMPscript keeps going to the default content, even when I put a simple IF/THEN statement.  Can someone offer a hand?

```
    %%[
       VAR @today, @launch, @launchcount, @air, @TotalOrderCount, @DaysSinceOrder,
       SET @today = format(now(), "MM/d/yyyy")
       SET @launch = "05/01/2014"
       SET @launchcount = DATEDIFF(@launch,@today,"D")
       SET @air = air_num
       SET @TotalOrderCount = TotalOrderCount1
       SET @DaysSinceOrder = DaysSinceOrder1
    ]%%

    %%[
       IF @air > "0" THEN

          SET @BTN1 = Lookup(@DataExt,"BTN1","Section",1,"Position",1)

          IF @BTN1 == 1 THEN SET @BTN1 = "http://img4.shopimg.ca/email/airplane/1x.png"
          ELSEIF @BTN1 == 2 THEN SET @BTN1 = "http://img4.shopimg.ca/email/airplane/2x.png"
          ELSEIF @BTN1 == 3 THEN SET @BTN1 = "http://img4.shopimg.ca/email/airplane/3x.png"
          ELSE SET @BTN1 = "http://img4.shopimg.ca/email/airplane/1x.png"
          ENDIF


          SET @BTN2 = Lookup(@DataExt,"BTN1","Section",1,"Position",2)
          IF @BTN2 == 1 THEN SET @BTN2 = "http://img4.shopimg.ca/email/airplane/1x.png"
          ELSEIF @BTN2 == 2 THEN SET @BTN2 = "http://img4.shopimg.ca/email/airplane/2x.png"
          ELSEIF @BTN2 == 3 THEN SET @BTN2 = "http://img4.shopimg.ca/email/airplane/3x.png"
          ELSE SET @BTN2 = "http://img4.shopimg.ca/email/airplane/1x.png"
          ENDIF

          SET @BTN3 = Lookup(@DataExt,"BTN1","Section",1,"Position",3)  
          IF @BTN3 == 1 THEN SET @BTN3 = "http://img4.shopimg.ca/email/airplane/1x.png"
          ELSEIF @BTN3 == 2 THEN SET @BTN3 = "http://img4.shopimg.ca/email/airplane/2x.png"
          ELSEIF @BTN3 == 3 THEN SET @BTN3 = "http://img4.shopimg.ca/email/airplane/3x.png"
          ELSE SET @BTN3 = "http://img4.shopimg.ca/email/airplane/1x.png"
          ENDIF

       ELSE
          SET @BTN1 = Lookup(@DataExt,"BTN1","Section",1,"Position",1)
          IF @BTN1 == 1 THEN SET @BTN1 = "http://img4.shopimg.ca/email/airplane/15x.png"
          ELSEIF @BTN1 == 2 THEN SET @BTN1 = "http://img4.shopimg.ca/email/airplane/2x.png"
          ELSEIF @BTN1 == 3 THEN SET @BTN1 = "http://img4.shopimg.ca/email/airplane/3x.png"
          ELSE SET @BTN1 = "http://img4.shopimg.ca/email/airplane/15x.png"
          ENDIF


          SET @BTN2 = Lookup(@DataExt,"BTN1","Section",1,"Position",2)
          IF @BTN2 == 1 THEN SET @BTN2 = "http://img4.shopimg.ca/email/airplane/15x.png"
          ELSEIF @BTN2 == 2 THEN SET @BTN2 = "http://img4.shopimg.ca/email/airplane/2x.png"
          ELSEIF @BTN2 == 3 THEN SET @BTN2 = "http://img4.shopimg.ca/email/airplane/3x.png"
          ELSE SET @BTN2 = "http://img4.shopimg.ca/email/airplane/15x.png"
          ENDIF

          SET @BTN3 = Lookup(@DataExt,"BTN1","Section",1,"Position",3)  
          IF @BTN3 == 1 THEN SET @BTN3 = "http://img4.shopimg.ca/email/airplane/15x.png"
          ELSEIF @BTN3 == 2 THEN SET @BTN3 = "http://img4.shopimg.ca/email/airplane/2x.png"
          ELSEIF @BTN3 == 3 THEN SET @BTN3 = "http://img4.shopimg.ca/email/airplane/3x.png"
          ELSE SET @BTN3 = "http://img4.shopimg.ca/email/airplane/15x.png"
          ENDIF


       ENDIF
    ]%%
```

Answer (score 1):

So @air = air_num. What is the value air_num?
Should air_num be a variable in which case it should be @air_num?
This value should determine what happens since it's the condition.

On the optimization side, I think you're better off using a lookuprows or lookuporderedrows here.

Comment: air_num is a loyalty program, and is a value in Lists, and not a Data Extension.  In the past I've declared the variables because list data (apparently) can be wonky in IF/THEN/ELSE statements.

Comment: Great so if air_num is a list attribute then that should be: set @air = AttributeValue(air_num), and this will pull the value of this attribute for a specific subscriber. I think this is not working as desires because it doesn't get to pull the value of air_num